# Parse.com - Getting pointer data contained in [PFUser currentUser]

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com iOS SDK, and I don't know what method I need to call to make sure that the PFUser currentUser contains the data for each pointer contained in it. It is probably very simple, but, as a beginner with this platform, I cannot find a solution.

Just to clarify, I am trying to get the username item in the following. It looks like it is always null, even though I am calling `[[PFUser currentUser] fetchIfNeeded]` before proceeding:

```
[[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"partner"] objectForKey:@"username"];
```

Thank you,

Andrea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in a single query by using `includeKey:`

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query includeKey:@"partner"];
[query includeKey:@"anotherPointerColumnName"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]
                             block:^(PFObject *populatedUser, NSError *error) {
    PFObject *partner = populatedUser[@"partner"];
    PFObject *another = populatedUser[@"anotherPointerColumnName"];
}];
```

You can also use deeper levels, so if `partner` contained a pointer in it you needed called `deeperPointerColumnName`:

```
[query includeKey:@"partner.deeperPointerColumnName"];
```

Then in your completion block you can read it after you get the partner:

```
PFObject *partner = populatedUser[@"partner"];
PFObject *deeper = partner[@"deeperPointerColumnName"];
```

Comment: yes, includeKey: is the one, this make the query include child PFObjects that have a reference stored at the provided key

Comment: what if the it's not `partner` but `partners` (array of pointers)?

Comment: The other issue with this is, it does not persist in `PFUser.currentUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround by myself. It looks like the solution is to call the `fetch` method on the pointer before proceeding:

```
[[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"partner"] fetch];
```

If there is a cleaner and swifter way of doing it (automatically for instance) I would really appreciate any advice.