# PFUser objects not retrievable from local Local Datastore (iOS)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I managed to save and retrieve custom objects from the local datastore with the help of Parse. Unfortunately the same method doesn't work for PFUser objects. Do I have to do something different?

This is what I implemented:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PFUser"];


    [query fromLocalDatastore];


    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {


        DDLogDebug(@"objects: %@", objects);


    }];
```

I retrieved the objects from the server and did `pinInBackground` on them (the method didn't give me an error so I guess the objects are saved correctly in the database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same problem. It comes from the declaration of your query. You should write:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

instead of :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PFUser"];
```

**In swift**,

the correct form is:

```
let localGuyQuery = PFUser.query()
```

And not:

```
let localGuyQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
```

Note that I only work in swift, I got inspiration for the objC version from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418986/parse-com-getting-pointer-data-contained-in-pfuser-currentuser)